# Google Play APK Expansion Downloader Library broken?

Tags: android, apk, expansion

I'm trying to use Google Play APK Expansion Downloader Library, but the freshly installed library seems to be broken: I'm seeing "src/src/com..." and "res/res/..." folders.

Anybody else seeing this? Moving everything one folder up seems to solve the problem, but why should Google distribute something broken? Am I doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cut them and paste(overwrite) to root library directory(downloader_library/).

I think Google made a mistake :p

Comment: OK, thanks, so it looks it's not me who's doing something wrong! :-)